# "Documents" folder is inaccessible after upgrade

Tags: nautilus, directory, 15.10, filemanager

I have just discovered that I cant open my documents folder. It is no longer in the bookmarks list in the file manager, but at the end of the list and when I click on it...it says the following:

[image]

I assume this has happened after the upgrade which I did 2 days ago, and since then I havent used this folder. I was just looking for it now and it was not where it used to be..plus it has become inaccessible. 
Any ideas why and how to recover my documents? or the entire folder the way it used to be?

Would it be a good idea to uninstall and then install the file manager simply from the software center?

New image of showing that I cant really add it back where it should be
[image]

Comment: And if you go into Terminal and run `ls -al ~`, is your Documents directory there? And if so, what is the output for it?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda hi there. Nah....it is missing. Really weird. But it is actually present in the file manager (but just the invalid shortcut). Is there a change log that could tell me what has gone wrong or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe do a search for it?

```
find ~/ -type d -name "Documents"
```

This will search from your `$HOME` (`~/`) folder and up. `d` means look for folders. If that doesn't work try replacing `d` with `f` to look for a file if it somehow got compressed.

If you are able to find the folder and have restored it to the correct place you should be able to edit your config to show in Nautilus again.

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

And add the files you want, eg.

```
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

This will place the folder under the `Places` tab in Nautilus.

Comment: this is weird. It got deleted. No clue how. I have restored it but it wont appear in the normal bookmarks and the system wont let me copy it back. It appears at the bottom of the right hand side list as if it were some regular folder. What can I do to totally restore it?

Comment: If you want to add a folder to your bookmarks on the left of Nautilus you can press `ctrl` + `D` which will allow you to edit your bookmarks. And you should be able to restore you Documents folder by copying it into your `$HOME` folder where it belongs. Hope this has helped!

Comment: I'll add a new screenshot (see as part of the original post). ctrl+d or manually adding it wont work because the adding option is grayed out. Plus it looks like it is already there, but not at the right position. Weird. Really.

Comment: Try editing this folder ... 

`gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: ok. Done. The line where it said "documents"...was simple saying "home"...wasnt saying "home/Documents". I guess simply because I accidentally deleted it and it got all messed up. Accepted your answer. Cheers. By the way.....where did you learn all these command lines? Or do you copy them from some place when you need them?

Comment: Pleasure! I usually just google them, one finds the answers quite easily here if one knows what to look for. So big thanks to all the pros around here!